# SML functor expose a type without exposing implementation (implementing sets)

Tags: functional-programming, sml, functor, signature, ml

I'm writing a functor to implement sets in standard ML. Since sets don't allow duplicates and I don't want it to be constrained to equality types, it's declared like this:

```
signature SET = sig
    type t
    type 'a set

    val add : t -> t set -> t set
    ...
end

functor ListSet (EQ : sig type t val equal : t * t -> bool end) :> SET = struct
    type t = EQ.t
    type 'a set = 'a list

    fun add x s = ...
    ...
end
```

I use `:>` so that list operations cannot be used on sets, hiding the internal implementation and allowing to change the representation (e.g. to a BST)

However, this also hides `type t`, therefore function `add` when used like this gives an error:

```
structure IntSet = ListSet (struct type t = int val equal = op= end);
val s0 = IntSet.empty
val s1 = IntSet.add 0 s0

Function: IntSet.add : IntSet.t -> IntSet.t IntSet.set -> IntSet.t IntSet.set
Argument: 0 : int
Reason:
  Can't unify int (*In Basis*) with
    IntSet.t (*Created from applying functor ListEqSet*)
    (Different type constructors)
```

Is there a way to keep the implementation hidden but somehow expose the type t? Or is there a better approach to implementing sets?

P.S. The main reason I can't have equality types is to allow sets of sets, and while I can keep the lists sorted and define `eqtype 'a set`, it adds unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need what's sometimes called a **translucent** signature ascription, that is, you hide some of the types and expose the others:

```
functor ListSet (Eq : EQ) :> SET where type t = Eq.t = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to expose the type `t` using a type refinement:

```
functor ListSet (Eq : sig type t val equal : t * t -> bool end) :> SET where type t = Eq.t =
struct
  ...
end
```

This is equivalent to an expansion of the signature `SET` where the type `t` is specified transparently as

```
type t = Eq.t
```